# updating state depending on another state fails in react using functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm creating a simple e-commerce project and while I'm calculating the total amount of products which depends on the total of each item it didn't update the state however when I console.log the function it calculates the amount !!.. so what's wrong with that?

[image: code issue]

Comment: Are you sure you're not using useState instead of useEffect?

Comment: OMG !! But how the total calculated with useState and why there’s no error for useState dependencies?!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [useEffect](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#usage) hook instead of [useState](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState) after the console log.

Comment: Yes i noticed that .. thanks .